# ¿Activar cuchilla de corte en Epson TM T20ii con DocPrintJob en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, impresión

Hola tengo el siguiente código

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        pras.add(new Copies(4));
        byte[] bytes = new String("Monkey el grande \nPrueba de impresion \n\n\n\n").getBytes(Charset.forName("Cp858"));
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
        pj.print(doc, pras);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Es el botón encargado de enviar una impresión a mi impresora epson, pero quiero que cuando termine de imprimir me corte el papel, la impresora tiene la cuchilla pero no se como activarla.

La imrpesora es una EPSON TM T20ii y la tengo conectada via usb.

Comment: Un saludo Estoy en la misma situación que tu y me preguntaba si pudiste solucionarlo, en caso de que si, ¿podrías compartir la solución conmigo? Muchas gracias y un fuerte abrazo.

Comment: como estas? Queria saber si lograste solucionar este problema. En caso de ser así podrías brindarme ayuda? ya que me encuentro igual que vos. Saludos Franco.